# jquery shortcut

Tags: jquery

This is not so importent question, I just wonder if this is possible.
I would like to do somethinf like this:

```
$elem.find('#a').click(...);
$elem.find('#b').click(...);
$elem.find('#c').click(...);
```

I one sentence like:

```
$elem
    .find('#a').click(...)
    .find('#b').click(...)
    .find('#c').click(...);
```

Is something like that possible?

I am asking about the find method/functionality only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$elem
    .find('#a').click(...).end()
    .find('#b').click(...).end()
    .find('#c').click(...).end();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's

```
$elem
    .find('#a').click(...).end()
    .find('#b').click(...).end()
    .find('#c').click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like: `$elem.find('#a,#b,#c').click(...);`

Comment: It is different function for each element.